# Images loaded with BitmapRegionDecoder are ok on simulator, but too large on device

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap, bitmapregiondecoder

In [a simple word game app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q7/MyDecoder) I load 26 letter tile images from a [PNG-image stripe](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png) with the following code:

[image: image stripe]

```
private static final CharacterIterator ABC = 
    new StringCharacterIterator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

private static HashMap<Character, Bitmap> sImages =
    new HashMap<Character, Bitmap>();

BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = null; 

InputStream is = sContext.getResources()
    .openRawResource(R.drawable.big_english);

try {   
        decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false); 
} catch (IOException ex) {
}       

int h = decoder.getHeight();
Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, h, h);

for (char c = ABC.first(); 
        c != CharacterIterator.DONE; 
        c = ABC.next(), r.offset(h, 0)) {

           Bitmap bmp = decoder.decodeRegion(r, null);
           sImages.put(c, bmp);
}
```

This works well in Android emulator:

[image: emulator]

But on a real Moto G device the letters are too big (Maybe by 1.5 factor? When I print `sContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` I for some reason get 2.0):

[image: Moto G device]

At the same time [the yellow square tile backround](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_tile.png) is shown correctly.

All ([big_tile.png](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_tile.png) and [big_english.png](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png) and [game_board.png](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/game_board.png)) are PNG-images - so why the difference?

Why does it happen and how to fix this please?

Should I maybe use `inDensity` or any other [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)?

Or is it because of my `getResources().openRawResource()` call - but what to use instead?

Comment: different screen resolution?

Comment: Yes, but the yellow square tile backround is shown correctly. And both ([big_tile.png](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_tile.png) and [big_english.png](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png)) are PNG-images - so why the difference?

Comment: place R.drawable.big_english in drawable-nodpi folder

Comment: But I don't want to waste memory on smaller Android devices. The [res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png) is 6240 x 240 pixels. I'd like to use a much smaller `res/drawable-ldpi/big_english.png` on low end devices.

Comment: have you put all the images in only Drawable folder or in all mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi folder?

Comment: I've put them into [res/drawable-mdi](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-mdpi) and [res/drawable-xxhdi](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q7/MyDecoder/res/drawable-xxhdpi)

Comment: Your drawable-xxhdpi/big_english.png and drawable-mdpi/big_english.png have the same size, you should scale it with the density like you did for big_tile.png. I am not sure that it will fix your problem though... Maybe you should try to draw the letter and the number with Canvas.drawText instead of using this BitmapRegionDecoder mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have the same problem with image, android devices came with many screen resolution. you will need either put alot of image into your drawable folder or give a set of rule of the image width and height to each screen resolution

```
for example:
if screen_resolution = 4 inch
int img_height = 200
int img_width = 200
else if screen_resolution = 5 inch
int img_height = 300
int img_width = 300
```

.
.
and so on
hope this can help you some how.

here some of my code(I use imageview not bitmap sorry):

int width, height;

```
   //calculate device screen
    DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float height=metrics.heightPixels/metrics.xdpi;
    float width=metrics.widthPixels/metrics.ydpi;
    float inchscreen = FloatMath.sqrt(height*height+width*width);


if (inchscreen > 4.1000)
    {
        //set image height for device above 4.1 inch screen
        height = 400;
        width = 400     
    }
else {
        //set image height for device below 4.1 inch screen
        height = 280;
        width = 280
    }

if (imgfile != null) {
                    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
                            getPackageName());
                    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    imageview.setImageDrawable(image);
                    imageview.getLayoutParams().height = h_display;
                    imageview.getLayoutParams().width = h_display;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share my own solution here.

The problem has been, that the yellow background for my letter tiles is a `Drawable` and the foreground is a `Bitmap` (read with the help of `BitmapRegionDecoder` from a PNG-stripe).

For some weird reason I still don't understand - their dimensions differ on some Android devices.

**(1)** So [my easiest workaround](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q10/MyDecoder/src/de/afarber/mydecoder/SmallTile.java) has been to scale the `Bitmap` (foreground with letter) into the bounds of the `Drawable` (yellow square background) every time the letter tile is being drawn:

```
private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(left, top);
    mImage.draw(canvas);
    Bitmap bmp = getImages().get(mLetter);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, mImage.getBounds(), mPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

**(2)** My [more involved workaround](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q10/MyDecoder2/src/de/afarber/mydecoder2/SmallTile.java) has been to scale the `Bitmap` just once - right after I read it with `BitmapRegionDecoder` and before I store it in a HashMap:

```
private static final CharacterIterator ABC = 
    new StringCharacterIterator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

private static HashMap<Character, Bitmap> sBitmaps = 
    new HashMap<Character, Bitmap>();

try {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(EN);
        BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);
        int h = decoder.getHeight();
        Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, h, h);
        for (char c = ABC.first();
             c != CharacterIterator.DONE;
             c = ABC.next(), r.offset(h, 0)) {
                Bitmap unscaled = decoder.decodeRegion(r, null);
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(unscaled, (int) (SCALE * width), (int) (SCALE * height), true);
                sBitmaps.put(c, scaled);
        }
} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

**(3)** Both methods worked, but on the older Google Nexus One device I couldn't see the foregrounds for some reason. At this point I've lost my nerve, stopped using `BitmapRegionDecoder` and just split the PNG-stripe with ImageMagick (the command is `convert square.png -crop 40x40 square_%d.png`). Now [my app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q10/MyTiles/src/de/afarber/mytiles/SmallTile.java) uses `Drawable` both for foregrounds and backgrounds of letter tiles and works on all devices starting with SDK level 8:

```
private static final String SQUARE = "square_";

private static final char[] LETTERS = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

private static HashMap<Character, Drawable> sLetters = 
    new HashMap<Character, Drawable>();

for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS.length; i++) {
    char c = LETTERS[i];
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(PREFIX + i, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    sLetters.put(c, d);
}
```

[image: emulator]